# What does "$R_{++}$" mean in "$x \log(x)$ is convex function either on $R_{++}$ or on $R_{+}$"?

Tags: convex-analysis

> $x \log(x)$ is convex function either on $R_{++}$ or on $R_{+}$.

$R_{+}$ is a common symbol that I know, but I don't know what $R_{++}$ is referring to.

Comment: $R_{++}$ refers to strictly positive

Comment: @user550103 doesn't $R_+$ mean the same thing?

Comment: @MrPie I have seen such notations. So, as I understand, $R_{++} \equiv R_{+}^* := R_{>0} = \{ x \in R \ | \ x > 0\}$ whereas $R_{+}  := R_{ \color{red} \geq0} = \{ x \in R \ |\ x { \color{red} \geq} 0\}$.

Comment: I see! Well, accepted comment then :)